# Bootstrap - could anyone give me any example, how to set up JS buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, button, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with Bootstrap's [stateful buttons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) - specifically with **Loading state**, but still can't find the right set up to get it working. I have a simple form based on AJAX, something like that:

```
<%=form_tag '/comments', :remote => true do %>
  <div><%=text_area_tag 'comment[text_comment]'%></div>
  <div><button class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="loading stuff..." >Post</button></div>
<%end%>
```

But still when I click on the **POST** button, so the form is sending, but the button effect (**loading stuff...**) is not displayed, like the example on Bootstrap's page.

Could anyone gives me a tip on how to fix it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to explicitly set that the button is in the loading state. Something like this:

```js
// Set up the buttons
$(button).button();    
$(button).click(function() {
    $(this).button('loading');
    // Then whatever you actually want to do i.e. submit form
    // After that has finished, reset the button state using
    // $(this).button('reset');
}
```

I've created a working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YCst4/1/).

Comment: thank you for the example, but gosh... I don't know, what I have wrong... when I try the example what you put on JSFiddle and put into the function alert, so the alert message is displayed, but the text **loading** into the button no... all Bootstrap files I have loaded...

Answer (score 4):

In the Bootstrap documentation, [the first mention of stateful buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons) gave me the impression that all I need to enable the stateful button is to provide the `data-loading-text` attribute:

> Add `data-loading-text="Loading..."` to use a loading state on a button.

If you are looking for this behaviour (and also expect it to work on `submit`, `input type="submit"`, etc), this jQuery selector should do the trick for you:

```
$(':input[data-loading-text]')
```

But you'll still need to attach your desired behaviour through an event handler, like `.click()`. This is [the jQuery for the stateful button in the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/application.js) (look for "fat-btn" in that javascript file):

```
.click(function () {
    var btn = $(this)
    btn.button('loading')
    setTimeout(function () {
        btn.button('reset')
    }, 3000)
})
```

So, putting that all together, we can do this:

```
$(':input[data-loading-text]').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this)
    btn.button('loading')
    setTimeout(function () {
        btn.button('reset')
    }, 3000)
})
```

I have a [working jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/n7n4w/](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/n7n4w/).

Comment: Great solution! My inherited code includes a mix of anchor tags and input buttons, so my JQuery select statement is simply "[data-loading-text]". Also, for standards compliance and clarity, please add semi-colons to the end of your lines.

Comment: @wloescher: The semicolons aren't included only because I copied the code verbatim from Bootstrap's code. Some linters will complain about "excess" seimcolons, so I'm guessing that's why *they* don't include them. I put them in my own code, for the same reasons you suggest them.

Comment: @wloescher: PS--consider using this selector: `$('a, :input').find('[data-loading-text]')...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need bootstrap-buttons.js. That's is HTM5, use the custom attributes. This sample does not depends of click event, it is a form submit

```
var btn = $(this).find("input[type=submit]:focus");
// loading
var loadingText = btn.data('loadingText');

if (typeof loadingText != 'undefined') {
    btn.attr("value", loadingText);
}
else {
    btn.attr("value", "Loading...");
}
btn.attr("disabled", true);

$.ajax({// long task
   complete: function () {
    // reset.. the same
});
```