# Force Bootstrap Form Validation Before Submit?

Tags: php, forms, validation, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on editing an existing PHP form that seems to use Bootstrap to do the field validation (telling me if a required field is missing).

Currently, when you fill out the form and click Submit, a modal pop-up comes up that basically just prints your form data so you can review it before submitting. Then, within that modal is another Submit button that actually submits the form.

However, the validation of determining whether all the required fields are filled out only happens on the 2nd Submit button, not the first.

Is there a way I can tell my 1st Submit button to do the validation, and only open the modal pop-up if the validation passes?

Comment: The validation script is probably 'connected' to the submit button via an 'onClick' or 'onSubmit' event. Can you show the HTML or script that is currently used? You might only have to move the function call of the validation script, but we cannot tell you how, until you provide some more details.

Comment: @ErikReder That's what I originally thought, but my submit button has no on-click functions or anything: <input type="submit" id="submit"  class="btn submitBtn px-3 py-2  btn-danger" name="submit" value="SUBMIT ORDER">

Comment: I'm not a bootstrap expert, but it's probably defined elsewhere, in the .js. Something like event.onClick("Button name", function())...

Comment: Actually, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486231/bootstrap-could-anyone-give-me-any-example-how-to-set-up-js-buttons:
$(button).click(function() {...}

Comment: I've determined that the validation is happening via bootstrap simply because the button type="submit". However, the 1st submit button that triggers the modal pop-up is type="button". When I change that to type="submit" it does my validation, but it skips over the pop-up and goes ahead and sends the form. Is there a way to set the 1st button type to submit, but not make it actually submit the form?

Comment: I think in any case it would be simpler (and more clean) to modify the bootstrap part...

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use Jquery. You can check with jquery first form values. If you need check with php you can use Ajax.